# Capturing which user created a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This must be very basic (I am a beginner), but I can't find the answer.  What is the best way to capture the user id from the session and stick it into the user_id field for a given post?

(A user has_many :posts and posts belongs_to :users)

```
def create

 @post = Post.new(params[:post])   (<---I want to get the user id from the session into here?)

end
```

Comment: How are you handling user authentication?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Starting to get the hang of this. Dogbert, I am using Omniauth to allow users to sign in with Twitter/Facebook etc. - don't want deal with my own authentications for now.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are handling authentication in such a way that you can access the current user using a method call (current_user):

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

And assuming you have a model that is setup kind of like this:

```
class User
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You can actually use the current_user to create an associated post like this:

```
current_user.posts.create(params[:post])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make:

```
params["post"].merge!({"user_id" => your_variable})
```

Anyway, Dogbert asked you an excellent question.